# IMAP server and mails

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

In Outlook 2007 I have a IMP account. The problem is that I regularly delete emails which means they go into the deleted items folder but they are not deleted from the server (as I think you have to tell it to purge the mails). Now If I delete the mails in my deleted emails folder they are (I think!) only deleted from the local machine - is that correct?

Is there a way to re-retrieve the deleted mails (which I deleted from the deleted emails folder) from the server? I could go to the server but handling is a pain so I would use Outlook to do it.

So the main question is

1. Using IMAP, the mails in the deleted email folder which are then deleted from that folder are just erased from the local machine
2. How can I get these emails back from the server with the email software? They are still on the serve. Can I somehow get them back into the postbox?